# Problem with running venv

Tags: 16.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, virtualenv

Attempting to create a new environment using venv, installed Ubuntu for WSL, updated, and installed venv without issue.

My problem is when I try to run venv, to create the new environment I used:

```
$ python3 -m venv ~/.virtualenvs/django
```

But when I try to run this from ~ (/home/username) using:

```
source ~/.virtualenvs/django/bin/activate
```

I get the following error:

```
bash: home/username/.virtualenvs/django/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

Previously, I set up venv using:

```
python3 -m venv /home/testenv
```

Then ran:

```
cd /home
```

Followed by:

```
source /home/testenv/bin/activate
```

Which worked. My question is am I simply in the wrong directory to run this? I have tried this from /home/username, /home, following the file path all the way to bin with no luck.

Comment: I just replicated using your code and had no problem. Check the spelling of the directories, and browse to check they exist.

Comment: Confrimed directory is there by doing cd ~/.virtualenvs/django/bin then used ls to list all files, activate is included. Are you referring to setting this up using python3 -m venv /home/testenv or $ python3 -m venv ~/.virtualenvs/django? What working directory did you run source from to activate venv, /home/username?

Comment: `$ python3 -m venv ~/.virtualenvs/django` and `source ~/.virtualenvs/django/bin/activate`

Comment: Nevermind, there must have been a typo that I kept trying to re-use, good call on checking syntax. Thanks!